unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded
I am getting this error and I can't solve it. Could you please help me in this issue. This is the error :
warning: default scripting plugin is disabled: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
error: unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded
and this is my buildgraddle code:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.finalproject"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.finalproject"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    implementation ("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828")
    implementation ("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
    implementation ("androidx.media:media:1.7.0")
}

